# How could I alter my code so that I am dynamically adding entities to my database using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-core, entity

I have a method where I take in an object which consists of multiple properties that each relate to tables in my database. What I currently am doing is using a foreach loop for each table object collection and adding them to my database. However, how can I alter this method so that I am able to dynamically add each object and not explicitly include each type that I need to add to? I am using EntityFrameworkCore(5.0.3).

```
void Add(RootObject obj)
{
    // Entity Framework database context.
    DbContext context = new DbContext();
    
    // TypeACollection is a Collection<TypeA> object.
    foreach (TypeA a in obj.TypeACollection)
    {
        // Adds the TypeA object to the DbSet<TypeA> that exists in my database context class.
        context.TypeAs.Add(a);
    }

    foreach (TypeB b in obj.TypeBCollection)
    {
        context.TypeBs.Add(b);
    }
   
    foreach (TypeC c in obj.TypeCCollection)
    {
        context.TypeCs.Add(a);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You need sample how to dynamically get property values and call generic method `context.Set<T>().Add()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below generic code for adding entities of different types.

```
context.Add(object);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrange?view=efcore-5.0) method

```
void Add(RootObject obj)
{
    // Entity Framework database context.
    DbContext context = new DbContext();

    context.AddRange(obj.TypeACollection);
    context.AddRange(obj.TypeBCollection);
    context.AddRange(obj.TypeCCollection);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Reason why you can use `context.Add/AddRange` over `context.set.Add/AddRange` is they both does the same thing. You can see that in [EFCore source code(InternalDBSet)](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs). See Add Method.